# Как правильно намеренно удлинить гласную в беллетристике?

Tags: правописание

Допустимо ли в художественной прозе применять дефис там, где автор хочет акцентировать внимание читателя на растянутом персонажем произношении слов, например: "на-а-много" для длинной "а"? Может быть, достаточно поставить дефис, как в "на-много"? Или же такой прием недопустим?

Answer (score 2):

В речи персонажей такое вполне допустимо, см., например, пьесу Евгения Шварца «Дракон».

Растягивают, как правило, ударные гласные.  Дефисы не обязательны: можно надо-о-олго, а можно и надооолго.

Answer (score 1):

Дефис тоже можно использовать, но нужно, чтобы до и после дефиса шла гласная:

> "на-а-амного"
>
> "на-амного"

Answer (score 0):

"Недопустим" слишком суровое слово, просто русскоязычный человек скорее всего воспримет дефис не как попытку удлинить гласную а, скорее, как попытку подтолкнуть к чтению по слогам.

В принципе, в традиции русского правописания дефис ставится в словах типа "не-а", "у-ху" (звукоподражание сове) чтобы [обозначить гортанную смычку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0). Также традиционно дефис используется для передачи сбитой речи (например, заикающегося).

Долготу же я бы просто рекомендовал обозначить через повторение гласной - единственно что конкретно в вашем случае очень сложно представить предударную а произносимой долго - "нааааааааааадолго" звучит неестественно, а вот "надооооооолго" я вполне себе представляю ;)